# SharePoint 2013 Custom Breadcrumb not structured correctly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, navigation

I am trying to put a custom breadcrumb on my On-prem SharePoint 2013 site.

I'm using the `SPXmlContentMapProvider` provider in my materpage:

```
<asp:sitemappath runat="server" sitemapproviders="SPXmlContentMapProvider" rendercurrentnodeaslink="false" hideinteriorrootnodes="false" ID="topBreadCrumb">
```

I created a simple `layout.sitemap` file:

```
<siteMap enableLocalization="true">
<siteMapNode title="" url="/">
<siteMapNode title="Policies" url="/OES/Policies/Forms/AllItems.aspx" />
<siteMapNode title="Procedures" url="/OES/Procedures/Forms/AllItems.aspx" />
<siteMapNode title="System Manuals" url="/OES/System Manual Training Materials  Employee Handboo/Forms/AllItems.aspx" />
<siteMapNode title="People Excellence Training" url="/OES/People Excellence Training/Forms/AllItems.aspx" />
<siteMapNode title="Forms and CheckLists" url="/OES/Forms and Checklists/Forms/AllItems.aspx" />    
<siteMapNode title="Records" url="/OES/Pages/records.aspx" >
<siteMapNode title="Corporate" url="/OES/Corporate/Forms/AllItems.aspx" parentUrl="/OES/Pages/records.aspx" />  
<siteMapNode title="Buslines" url="/OES/Buslines/Forms/AllItems.aspx" parentUrl="/OES/Pages/records.aspx" />    
</siteMapNode>
```

Out of box sitemap nodes below this:

As you can see the record sitemapnode has children `Corporate` and `Buslines`.

I would expect the bread crumb to go like this:

```
Home > Records > Corporate
```

or

```
Home > Records > Buslines
```

However it is rendering like:

```
Home > Corporate > Records > Corporate
```

Notice the `Corporate` is below `Records`, even though in the sitemaps file `Corporate` is a child of `Records`?

Answer (score 0):

Is there some alternate Css being applied to that site, I experienced such issue before where alternate Css was causing the issue, I had to reset the css to use the default css of the master page. After that I started re-applying the changes again.

Comment: I didnt find any CSS causing this issue, but I just fixed it with JavaScript